# Execute wincsp command line arguments from within R

Tags: r, command-line, winscp

I have some command line batch code which I can run in my windows command prompt just fine. I'm basically pushing a local file text file to a remote server using WinSCP command line arguments - https://winscp.net/eng/docs/commandline. These are the commands I use, in order:

to open up winscp command line:

```
winscp
```

then to open connection to my server through ssh:

```
open sftp://myUserName:myPassword@theRemoteServer.net
```

upload file to remote server:

```
put directoryMyLocalFileIsIn\fileToUpload.csv /locationOnRemoteServer/whatToNameFileOnRemoteServer.csv
```

then close connection:

`close`

This all works fine. But, I want to run this all from within RStudio.. My issue - 
after I run:

```
shell.exec("winscp")
```

I can see the winscp shell is opened up. But when I try and run my next commands like these:

```
shell.exec("open sftp://myUserName:myPassword@theRemoteServer.net")
```

It just doesnt run in that winscp shell that opened up.. I've also used all sorts of combinations of R commands like shell, system2 and shell.

Again, I can open up the winscp shell successfully from within R. But I cant figure out how to then run commands in that shell. Anyone know how to do this?

Thank you.

Comment: If you're using the latest Windows 10 version, note that it has ssh and scp installed. No more need to use putty and WinSCP.

Comment: what has ssh and scp installed.. the windows 10 command line?

Comment: I think Hong is referring to running Linux on Windows as such: https://www.howtogeek.com/249966/how-to-install-and-use-the-linux-bash-shell-on-windows-10/

Comment: FWIW there's an [`ssh` package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ssh/index.html) for R that includes `scp` capability right from R.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to call WinSCP and specify all commands using a single call from R. The best way to do this is to save your WinSCP commands in a single text file, e.g. `myscript.txt`:

```
open sftp://myUserName:myPassword@theRemoteServer.net
put directoryMyLocalFileIsIn\fileToUpload.csv /locationOnRemoteServer/whatToNameFileOnRemoteServer
exit
```

Then, from the command line, you can call WinSCP as follows (see the [WinSCP documentation](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/scripting#example)):

```
winscp.com /script=myscript.txt
```

(you might need to specify the exact path for WinSCP and myscript.txt)

Finally, to accomplish this from R, use the `system2` command as follows:

```
system2(
  "winscp.com",
  args = c("/script=myscript.txt"))
```

Again, you might need to specify the paths to `winscp.com` and `myscript.txt`.